# Spring mvc and dynamic submit form

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to learn Spring mvc and JSP, and I have a problem that how I can get the value of select list dynamically?

If I have a select list:

```
<select name="qty>
<option>1</option>
</select>
```

and in the spring mvc, I can get the it value by using @RequestParam("qty") int qty. However, If I surround the select list with a loop:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="10">
    <select name="qty>
    <option>1</option>
    </select>
</c:forEach>
```

I am thinking of using an array @RequestParam("qty") int[] qty but I think it is not a good option because well the form is much more complicated that this example, and assume that the qty is associate with a specific item. So how can get the qty of the item which the user has selected during submitting the form?

Comment: Do you have a backing object for the form? Is the form wrapped in spring's form tag so that when the user submits the form, Spring will handle populating the backing object? Do you have a controller set up to handle submission of this form?

Comment: @adchilds Thanks for quick response. I also thinking to create a dummy  class so that I can take advance of spring form. But I am not sure it is a good choice to do so? If it is a better choice, will it the same think to get the object in the controller using array?